# How to draw on a tikz picture without shifting it

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm trying to draw on a tikz image. When I add arrows the pictures shifts to the right out of the frame.
I'm a newby in latex as you can see. I couldn't find a proper solution or couldn't adapt the ones I found to my needs. Any ideas on this?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=18cm]{filename}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]

        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
      \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    
    %
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.57) -- (0.07, 0.57);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.18, 0.57)  node[anchor=west] {Kühlkanäle};
    
    % 
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.8) -- (0.2, 0.63);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.25, 0.8)  node[anchor=west] {Stirnseitiger Reibring};
    
    %
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.4) -- (0.2, 0.4);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.25, 0.8)  node[anchor=west] {Stirnseitiger Reibring};
    
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: shifted tikz image]

Comment: See also `pgfinterruptboundingbox` (environment, page 1080) and `\pgfresetboundingbox` (page 1105).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tikzpicture` shifts because tikz computes the bounding box from all coordinates mentioned in the picture. This includes the labels that protrude from the image.

Include the line

```
\useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);
```

after defining the node `image`. This tells tikz to use this rectangle as bounding box instead of computing the box itself.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

18cm is a bit large for the image. But beside this: you can use a scope with overlay:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=18cm]{example-image}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]

        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
      \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }

    \begin{scope}[overlay] %<----
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.57) -- (0.07, 0.57);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.18, 0.57)  node[anchor=west] {Kühlkanäle};

    %
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.8) -- (0.2, 0.63);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.25, 0.8)  node[anchor=west] {Stirnseitiger Reibring};

    %
     \draw [thick, ->] (-0.05, 0.4) -- (0.2, 0.4);
     \filldraw [thick] (-0.25, 0.8)  node[anchor=west] {Stirnseitiger Reibring};
    \end{scope} %<--------
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```